# Why isn't mask working - compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, error, masking

I don't understand Blender and how it operates.

1. The following mask and compositing node tree "RH Scroll Door Frame RH" is set up exactly the same as the one above it (everything within the mask is black hence invisible, everything outside it is white therefore visible).
2. The above node tree is working correctly (this is the dark door in between the two stone door pillars), the mask for this part is working as expected.
3. This node tree however is not, you can see the part of the image inside the mask is still visible and it should not be. Why is it doing this?

This is a fairly simple compositing task but Blender is so frustrating to use because of simple things like this working in one instance then not another.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think i've sorted this, and it makes sense. I changed the render output size to 10 percent and with a scale node before the composite node, so any masks likely aren't even in the frame when rendering. After muting the scale node, and setting back to 100 percent render size the masks are working again.

Just left this question online in case someone else may find it useful.